Integrating Pro Tools and a Roland TD-07 Drum Sound Module
I have a Pro Tools Artist subscription, and my version of Pro Tools for Windows 10 is 2024.10. This question is on my website, with images, in case that might be helpful.
The TD-07 support site provides the Windows 10 driver, which seems to work fine. This question assumes that the TD-07 ASIO driver is installed and working. It provides the TD-07 [Emulated] input and ouput ports.
Define the TD-07 MIDI Device

Select the Setup / MIDI / MIDI Studio Setup... menu.
Push the Create button.
Name the new instrument TD-07.
For Manufacturer, select Roland.
For Model, the most appropriate choices are TD-5, TD-7 and TD-10. These 3 choices are old Roland products that were discontinued years ago. Note that the TD-7 is not the same as the TD-07. The Roland dealer who sold me the drum kit suggested that the TD-7 was the best choice; however, it might be better to somehow define a new model, but I do not know how to do that. I selected TD-7 for now.
For Input port, select TD-07 [Emulated].
For Output port, select TD-07 [Emulated].
I left all the Send Channels and Receive Channels selected. Perhaps that might need to be narrowed down in the future.
To save the configuration, press the Export button and save with file type .dms. I saved to E:\media\proTools\midi_studio_setup.dms
Close the MIDI Studio Setup window.

The new Pro Tools TD-07 MIDI device is now available in all Pro Tools sessions.
Using the TD-07 MIDI Device
The TD-07 MIDI device defined above allows you to play drum parts into a Pro Tools session and trigger a drum insert, for example, EZ Drummer 3 or Xpand!2. You can create an instrument track for playback only, or you can create an aux track and an associated MIDI track for recording and playback. Instrument tracks and MIDI tracks can both accept input from the TD-07 MIDI device.
Pro Tools Options / MIDI Thru must be enabled.

TD-07 As a Drum Synthesizer
I need help with this part - it does not work yet.
To use the drum sounds from the Roland module, first create a new MIDI track using ticks.

Now create a new stereo Aux track, also using ticks.

Assign the output of the MIDI track to the TD-07 MIDI device, like this:

I do not know how to proceed from here. The drummer should cause audio output somehow. What needs to be done?
Does Not Work With an Instrument Track
I am unable to configure an instrument track to use the TD-07 MIDI device. Perhaps there is a way, but I do not know what that might be.
For example, let’s create a new stereo instrument track for the TD-07 MIDI device. Instrument tracks are usually created in ticks.

Now assign an insert to the new instrument track so sound is generated from MIDI data. I used EZdrummer 3 (stereo), but any stereo instrument would work.

I am unable to configure the instrument track to accept input from the TD-07 MIDI device. The Predefined MIDI devices do not show up.

Suggestions?
